# Border radius gap

Tags: html, css

I added border and border radius to div. Inside that div there is `::before` which inherit `border-radius` from `.wrapper` but somehow border is displayed wrong. There is visible gap.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper::before {
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(1, 117, 255, 0.9);
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: inherit;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Can this be fixed by css?

Comment: The outer radius should be larger by the thickness of the border.

Comment: This might help: https://joshnh.com/weblog/getting-inner-border-radius-just-right/

Comment: I would use a box shadow for the inner border: https://jsfiddle.net/d5j6usnp/

Answer (score -1):

For your current layout, `border-radius: 30px;` for `::before` works:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper::before {
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(1, 117, 255, 0.9);
  border-radius: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```